# Flutter Web: What are the side effects of using it to build a web app

Tags: flutter, web-applications, flutter-web, dart2js

Recently, I have been exploring the Flutter API tools and builds, even the flutter-web project. So what I really want to  understand is the flutter-web support which makes it possible to compile an existing or new app into a `web app`, to run on web browsers. The question is: "What are the possible side effects you are likely going to experience when using  flutter-web to build web apps". Thanks in advance.

Comment: hope my reply answered your question.

Answer (score 1):

The main reason why it is not advised to use `flutter-web` is beacuse it is not yet in a stable version.
Therefore if offers `low-performance` compare to normal web-apps.

For more details on the advantages and disadvantages of using `flutter-web`.
Check the article below. It will be of help.

[Read more on Flutter Web](https://medium.com/nonstopio/my-experience-with-flutter-web-performance-advantages-disadvantages-d32ffa4e8bc1)

I hope this answers your question.

Comment: Cool...was able to collect some info using the link. Thanks

Comment: Glad it helped.